# Object reference not set to an instance of an object MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I already saw a bunch of these posts but none helped me because most weren't applied to C# and MVC.

I have the Create for an object named TipoImovel. This object has an auto-generated ID (int), a description (string - tipoImovel) and then the possibly NULL value to a sub-TipoImovel (int? and then the reference TipoImovel). If it's confusing think of it like you create a House (TipoImovel). You can then create a Pool (also TipoImovel) and say it's a sub-type of TipoImovel making it a Pool which is subTipoImovel of House (House with pool). Sorry for the names but they are in my native language. If any questions arise around them please say.

Now here's the code:

TipoImovel.cs

```
public class TipoImovel
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo de Imóvel")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string tipoImovel { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sub-Tipo de:")]
    public int? tipoImovelID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Sub-Tipo de:")]
    public virtual TipoImovel subTipoImovel { get; set; }

}
```

TipoImovelController.cs (GET and POST methods)

```
// GET: TipoImovel/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.tipoImovelID = new SelectList(db.TipoImovel, "ID", "tipoImovel");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: TipoImovel/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,tipoImovel,tipoImovelID")] TipoImovel TipoImovel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.TipoImovel.Add(TipoImovel);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.tipoImovelID = new SelectList(db.TipoImovel, "ID", "tipoImovel", TipoImovel.tipoImovelID);
        return View(TipoImovel);
    }
```

Create.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>TipoImovel</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tipoImovel, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tipoImovel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tipoImovel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tipoImovelID, "tipoImovelID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("tipoImovelID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.subTipoImovel, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

The error comes up because the TipoImovel I receive in the POST method comes as NULL. The form is properly created retreiving any (manually introduced) existing TipoImovel and showing them in the ComboBox but upon hitting "Create" it crashes.

I've been around this problem for 2 days and I can't fix it. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Pic of generated HTML:

[image: Genereted HTML]

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: ViewBag.tipoImovelID = new SelectList(db.TipoImovel, "ID", "tipoImovel", TipoImovel.tipoImovelID);

This one but it shouldn't even get there. It should enter the IF clause.

Comment: the entire parameter is null in in the POST, or the properties on it?

Comment: Where is db.TipoImovel defined in the Create GET method?

Comment: You're passing `TipoImovel.tipoImovelID` to the SelectList constructor - this is probably `null`

Comment: This may be related to the way your param is named. You have a class named `TipoImovel` and an action parameter named `TipoImovel`. Your code is probably choking because it's picking the wrong one to reference. Try naming your param in lowercase (i.e. `tipoImovel`) to remove the abiguity.

Comment: db.TipoImovel is defined as a global variable in the beginning of the controller as such:         private ImobiliariaContext db = new ImobiliariaContext();

I had the TipoImovel as tipoImovel and also didn't work. I changed to as it is because it was a suggestion I saw on another post. I'll change it back because it does make more sense but that's not it.

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? Also, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841388/selectlist-pulling-info-from-viewbag-not-creating-value-in-generated-html) to learn how to create a drop down list with a ViewBag.

Comment: Edited the HTML. The drop down is created properly, it's the object which isn't created properly.

Comment: You really should tidy up your names so you don't have duplicates everywhere. You've got a model TipoImovel with an id ID and a convention-named id TipoImovelID. You're then passing a TipoImovel TipoImovel to your POST and calling on TipoImovel. You've then also got a TipoImovel property in your TipoImovel which isn't a TipoImovel. Further, you have a ViewBag.TipoImovelId which doesn't hold a TipoImovelId but holds a selectlist!? No wonder it's difficult to debug!

Comment: Yes, I totally agree, I'll try to clean up the names later so it's easier to debug. I've tried so many combinations which resulted in the mess it is in now. I apologize for that and as soon as I can I'll edit it to a better state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model has a property `string TipoImovel` but you have also named the parameter of your POST method `TipoImovel` (and even more confusing, your class is also named `TipoImovel`)

Change the name of the parameter so that it dos not match one of the properties of your model, say

```
public ActionResult Create(TipoImovel model)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: I love you. And it was such a simple thing. I literally changed it to model and it worked. Small things... Thank you!